# JQuery add validation method to validate regarding another element in the form

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to create a custom validation method in JQuery and I can't manage to make it work properly.

Here is what I want to do :

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="fld-stories">Stories</label>
    <select id="fld-stories" class="valid" name="stories" title="">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="1" label="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" label="2">2</option>
        <option value="3" label="3">3</option>
        <option value="4" label="4">4</option>
        <option value="5" label="5">5</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="row_master_bedroom_location" class="row">
    <label for="fld-master_bedroom_location">Master Bedroom Location</label>
    <select id="fld-master_bedroom_location" name="master_bedroom_location" title="">
        <option value="up">Upstairs</option>
        <option value="down">Downstairs</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

If the user selects the master bedroom location to be upstairs (see second select), the number of stories for the house should be superior or equal to 2 (which is logical since the master bedroom can't be upstairs if there is only one story).

To do so I try to add a custom method to my JQuery validator :

```
$.validator.addMethod('masterBedroomLocation', function(value, element, params) {
    if (value == 'up' && $("#fld-stories").val() < 2){
        return false;
    }
}, 'You cannot select &quot;Upstairs&quot; for a one&ndash;story home');
```

I'm not sure how to get the value of another element in the form, I tried the JQuery old fashion way but it doesn't seem to work.

For additional information, I add the custom method in a global javascript files, in a function that binds the JQuery validation to every forms that have a special class name.

Comment: Instead of a custom validation method, why not simply modify the appropriate select list options?  It will make far more sense that the user not be presented with inapplicable options after making a selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work.
It looks like the Jquery selector 
    $("#fld-stories")
works properly.
For some reason I don't know, the method works if I invert the way I do my check and return a true instead of a false.

Here is the new method :

```
$.validator.addMethod('masterBedroomLocation', function(value, element, params) {
    if (value == 'up' && $("#fld-stories").val() >= 2){ 
        return true;
    }
}, 'You cannot select &quot;Upstairs&quot; for a one&ndash;story home');
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved my code a little bit.
Here is the new method :

```
$.validator.addMethod('masterBedroomLocation', function(value, element, params) {
    if($('#fld-master_bedroom_location').val() == 'down'){
        return true;
    }
    else if($('#fld-master_bedroom_location').val() == 'up' && $("#fld-stories").val() >= 2){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}, 'You cannot select &quot;Upstairs&quot; for a one&ndash;story home');
```

I hope this can help somebody.